# Stsadm export hangs after sometime

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

I am trying to export a SharePoint site using stsadm, but everytime I start the process it hangs at a particular point in the export process, it always hangs exporting a particular list item. But if I delete the list item the export hangs at the  previous item.

I have waited for mre tan 10 hours for the export to complete but it does not complete.

Please let me know if there is anything i need to do to complete the export.

One more additional information is that the export works for other sites on the server.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the list item causing the problem is the one *after* it hangs?